# Get reference to base URL in AngularJS controller

Tags: angularjs

I am using HTML5 mode in AngularJS and I have a `<base href="/some/base/path" />` defined in the `<head>` section of my HTML file.

What is the best way of reading this value in AngularJS? I understand that you can just read this HTML tag with jQuery, but something tells me this is not the most elegant way of doing it.

**What I want to achieve**

I would like to compose URL dynamically from controller. For instance, current page is `http://localhost/myapp/some/custom/page/` where `http://localhost/myapp` is a base url. I want to build `http://localhost/myapp/another/page` url in angular controller by doing the following

```
baseUrl + `/another/page`
```

Comment: Why do you need to read it? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: This feels like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/297619).  Angular has ways to handle your URL strings, URL parameters, etc..  Usually knowing the `<base>` isn't necessary to perform any angular logic, and as @JBNizet stated, you haven't mentioned what you want to achieve by reading this information.

Answer (score 1):

AngularJS doesn't really have any functions for extracting attributes from tags. However, there are a workaround. But the pure javascript way I added at the bottom of the answer might be the best solution for you.

Let's say you change the base tag:

```
<base ng-controller="MyController" data-href="/some/base/path">
```

In your controller you can do the following to access data-href:

```
app.controller('MyController', function ($scope, $attrs) {
  console.log($attrs.href); // Prints '/some/base/path'
});
```

Or you can do it in pure javascript with:

```
var url = document.getElementsByTagName('base')[0].getAttribute('href');
```

Comment: Thanks, I know that it's possible to access base via DOM, but I thought there is slightly more elegant solution out there for AngularJS